# "Take for vaccination" vs "take to get vaccinated"

Tags: word-usage

What sounds better out of the two:

> I took my dog for vaccination.
>
> I took my dog to get vaccinated.

Maybe the first sentence does not work. I feel that the second one sounds natural. Am I right in thinking so? Does the first one really sound unnatural as I feel?

P.S. Is the use of "as I feel" in the end natural?

Comment: **To be vaccinated...** works best

Comment: So @RonaldSole doesn't the second one work too? Can it only be "I took my dog to be vaccinated"? And the first one is wrong, right?

Comment: Some people might say **to get vaccinated**.  A quick check on Google Books Ngram Viewer shows that **to be vaccinated** is about 9 times more common. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+be+vaccinated%2Cto+get+vaccinated&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20be%20vaccinated%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20get%20vaccinated%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cto%20be%20vaccinated%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20get%20vaccinated%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1):

Your second option is common and natural.

Vaccination is a noun, so the first is very awkward. Other options to consider:

> I got my dog vaccinated.
>
> I took my dog to the vet for **a** vaccination.
>
> The vet vaccinated my dog.
>
> My dog was vaccinated.
>
> My dog has been vaccinated.